# Get iterate value returned to place into tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to iterate through some data I got from an API json object and put it into a tag. The problem is that when I place it into a tag or use `console.log(text)` it prints all the appended data in a row instead of the result.

Basic sample -
What I am getting now:

```
data1
data1,data2
data1,data2,data2
```

What I am looking for:

```
data1
data2
data3
```

here is the code:

```js
const url = "https://alloysystems.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets";
fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      // needed to base64 encode my key with ":x" at the end of the api key then I used that for the authorization header.
      "authorization": "Basic YOUWILLNEVERGETMYKEYLOL"
    }
  })
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(data => {
    let text = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const pre = document.createElement('pre');
      text += "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].subject) + "<br>" +
        "CC Emails: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].cc_emails).replace("[]", "No Emails are CC'd").replace("[", "").replace("]", "") + "<br>" +
        "Ticket Creation Date: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].created_at) + "<br>" +
        "Ticket Status: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].status).replace("2", "Open").replace("3", "Pending").replace("4", "Resolved").replace("5", "Closed").replace("6", "Waiting On Customer");
      pre.innerText += text
      console.log(text)
      document.querySelector('span.ms-font-m').appendChild(pre);
    }
  })
```

Here is the result:
[image]

I also tried using a return function like so `return text` or `return pre` but that caused a problem as the for loop would stop on the first loop.

Any ideas would be awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create elements inside the loop if each entry had its own `<pre>` container.  Like this:

```js
const data = [{'subject':'test1'},{'subject':'test2'}];
const output = document.querySelector('span.ms-font-m');

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  let text = "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].subject) + "<br>";
  let pre = document.createElement('pre');
  pre.innerHTML = text;
  output.appendChild(pre);
}
```

```html
<span class="ms-font-m"></span>
```

But since you are concatenating all entries into one variable `text`, you only need to create one `<pre>` element and you can handle it outside the loop. Populate and append it once, after the loop.

```js
const data = [{'subject':'test1'},{'subject':'test2'}];
const pre = document.createElement('pre');
let text = "";

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  text += "Subject: " + JSON.stringify(data[i].subject) + "<br>";
}

pre.innerHTML = text;
document.querySelector('span.ms-font-m').appendChild(pre);
```

```html
<span class="ms-font-m"></span>
```